# unbalancing lights

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinatorial-designs, probabilistic-method

I'm reading the following notes on unbalancing lights, http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/cs271/n5.pdf. The question i have is regarding the first page. Where it says

> Consider a square $n \times n$ array of lights (see Figure 5.1). There is one switch corresponding to each row and
>   each column (i.e., $2n$ switches). Throwing a switch changes the state of all the lights in the corresponding
>   row or column. We now consider the problem of setting the switches so as to maximize the number of lights
>   that are on, starting from an arbitrary initial on/off configuration of the lights.
>
> Note first that, if we set all the switches independently and uniformly at random, we would expect $\mathbb{E}(|\#\mathrm{ON}-\#\mathrm{OFF}|)\sim O(\sqrt(n^{2}))=O(n)$ Hence we would expect to be able to achieve about $\frac{n^{2}}{2}+O(n)$ lights on.  (Note that we
>   can always ensure that at least half are on simply by flipping all the switches if necessary.)

Questions:
Firstly do they mean each switch is switched on or not with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ or we can flick one switch which is picked uniformly at random?

Secondly I don't see how the intuition in $\mathbb{E}(|\#\mathrm{ON}-\#\mathrm{OFF}|)\sim O(\sqrt(n^{2}))=O(n)$. Could someone help explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: You lost an exponent in the quote.  We would expect to be able to achieve $\frac {n^2}2+O(n)$ lights on.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to imagine each light as an independent coin flip.  The standard deviation in the number of heads in $k$ flips is $\frac 12 \sqrt k$  When you take the difference between the heads and tails you double it because if one is high the other is low, so the $\frac 12$ goes away, and $k=n^2$ so we expect the standard deviation in the difference to be about $n$.

Comment: This was my first thought, but we can't really treat the number of "on" lights as a binomial random variable with $n^2$ experiments, can we? I don't think the lights are mutually independent the way we would need. If you have 4 lights at the corners of a rectangle which are all initially "on", then no matter which switches we hit, an even number of those lights will be on, which means we don't have mutual independence.

Comment: (I guess it's not really clear whether the snippet is just appealing to the binomial *intuition* to motivate the better estimate, or whether it's claiming that there's a rigorous reason that we can easily get $n/2 + O(n)$ lights.)

Comment: You are correct that they are not truly independent, but the results of assuming independence are often quite accurate.  The author then goes on to show you can do much better.  I would say he is appealing to the binomial intuition.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. So when they say "if we set all the switches independently and uniformly at random" what they mean is essentially think of the case where each bulb is on or off independently of all other bulbs?

Comment: If so how did you arrive at a deviation when they are working out the expected difference in successes and failures? One way i tried to look at this was to say imagine $X_{ij}=1$ if $ij$ is on and $X_{ij}=-1$ if it is off with each $X_{ij}$ independent and on with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Then $X=\sum_{ij \in [n]^{2}} |X_{ij}|=|\#\mathrm{Successes}-\#\mathrm{Failures}|$ and so we must have $\mathbb{E}(X)=O(n)$ in this case then?

Comment: Your last two comments are spot on.  Yes, they are handwaving in going from setting the switches randomly to having the bulbs on/off independently, but it is probably very close.  Your last is how they got to $O(n)$

Comment: Ok thanks, i've tried the calculations and i can't see quite how to get to $O(n)$. I didn't quite understand your deviation argument. Here is what i tried since   $|\# \mathrm{Successes}-\# \mathrm{Failures}|=n-2\#\mathrm{successes}$ and so $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(2|\frac{n}{2}-\#\mathrm{Successes}|)=2\mathbb{E}(| \frac{n}{2}-\#\mathrm{Successes}|)$ this looks similar to standard deviation but it is the absolute deviation from the mean when we consider only the number of successes. What can i do to show this is $O(n)$?  Thanks!!

Comment: Big O only cares about the scale with $n$, not about the coefficient in front.  The "expected" deviation from the mean is about $1\sigma$.  You would also expect the absolute deviation to be about this.  You could argue for a factor 2 or 3, but it won't scale with $n$, so it will still be $O(\sqrt n)$.  Note that you reused $n$ generically, not for the problem at hand where we have $n^2$ lights.

Comment: Ok, so here is where i'm a little confused (working in the general binomil case with $n$ rather than $n^{2}$) we know the standard deviation is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and the standard deviation is the square root of the variance. I'm still struggling to link the absolute deviation into this. So far the only link i see is that $\mathbb{E}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|) \leq \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X))^{2})=\mathrm{var}(X)=O(n)$. So i can obtain $\mathbb{E}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|)=O(n)$ but not $O(\sqrt{n})$.